# Shift bufferedimage 1 row or column

Tags: java, bufferedimage

Okay sorry if this has been asked an answered.  I am trying to figure out if this is even possible.  I am attempting to make my game's drawMap method more efficient.

It goes through a loop and draws each tile to a bufferedImage in the usual fashion.  Code simplified below to show logic.

```
for (int x = 0; x < xTiles; x++){
    for (int y = 0; y < yTiles; y++){
        //10 x 10 map
        SpriteStore.get().getSprite("res/images/tiles/" + groundLayer[count] + ".png");
    }
}
```

Each time the player walks (North || NorthEast || NorthWest || East || South || SouthEast || SouthWest || West) I draw the full map over again.

For example, during a North move, is it possible to 'shift' the entire image down 1 row(throwing away the bottom row, 10 columns wide) and simply refresh the top row?  Is this possible without having to loop through the whole set - which will likely defeat the purpose(avoid iterating the entire map)?  I am not sure if I am just burnt out or what, but I am having a hard time coming up with the logic for this one.

Thanks so much for reading this and your brainpower!!

Comment: Create a new BufferedImage, copy (draw) the old one onto, offset by the number of new titles you need. Draw the new titles into the new space...

Comment: thanks MadProgrammer... you always seem to help me out!

Comment: Hope it all helps in the long run ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer any chance you found an example on this... still unable to get it to work.

Comment: nevermind I am getting closer.. and will post some code examples when I'm done for anyone else who finds this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refine MadProgrammer's comment:

You can use [Graphics.drawImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) to do what you want - set (x,y) to be negative to shift left/up or positive to shift right/down.  Then you just have to draw the "new" regions.

And, if you aren't already, zebediah49's suggestion about re-using a pair of buffered images instead of creating a new one per frame will be a massive boost.

Comment: awesome thanks for the help, going to take a stab at this after some rest! :)

Comment: any chance you found an example on this... still unable to get it to work. :(

Comment: nevermind I am getting closer.. and will post some code examples when I'm done for anyone else who finds this

Answer (score 1):

I would go with alternating between two buffers:

```
draw oldImg to newImg at appropriate offset
draw remaining new data to newImg
draw newImg to screen
swap oldImg and newImg (temp=new;new=old;old=temp)
```

You could create a new image every frame, but that would probably stress your garbage collector more than you want.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion I am going to give it a shot, excited to have it be more efficient